# Can't Open a Chest in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I cannot seem to open a chest in Minecraft Pocket Edition. I tried clicking on it, which resulted in the chest breaking or not doing anything. I haven't run into that problem on the PC.

Comment: Is there a solid block above the chest? Then it won't open

Comment: In the future, remember to add the version you're using, and the game mode, if there are more than one.

Comment: There is not a solid block over it

Comment: Did you right click?  Left clicking breaks the chest... (er, the equivalent, I don't do Minecraft PE)

Comment: @Mɪɴɪʙɪᴛs if possible, could you please add a screenshot of the chest (and local surroundings) into the question body? I may be able to figure it out based on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in creative, as of the latest version (Alpha 0.8.1) when this question was posted, you couldn't open chests in creative.

Answer (score -1):

Some other people might but I think you can't because there is an update that you need to do to be able to get hoppers and redstone stuff and also letting you get into chests and other things, too! (I don't know if you can, but I think you can do it in survival)

Comment: Try to reword your answer, punctuation helps with readability too.